# FFMPEG demux .264 for burning in scenarist

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264, bluray

I have a very specific pipeline I need to set up, it starts with an mov file from Avid which gets transcoded to mkv for internal review and .264 for burning to Blu-ray in Scenarist. It goes:

`.mov (DNxHD) -> .mkv (h264) -> .264`

For purposes of quality and speed I transcode to .mkv in FFMPEG and then when the time comes to make a Blu-ray I demux the mkv to the .264, however I'm told this is throwing a very ambiguous error in scenarist and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Interestingly if I transcode directly to .264 instead of demuxing it there is no problem, so this appears to be a metadata issue. Here's the demux recipe I'm using:

`-i input.mkv -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb output.264`

Here's the transcode recipe if that is useful:

`-i input -c:v libx264 -preset fast -tune film -b:v 20000k -maxrate 35000k -bufsize 30000k -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -x264opts bluray-compat=1:open-gop=1:slices=4:keyint=24 -r fps outfile.mkv`

Comment: Add `-bsf:v dump_extra=k` and check. Annex B bsf is auto-inserted since v3.2

Comment: @Gyan Just tried that and Scenarist says "Media file invalid". If I inspect the file it seems almost all metadata is now gone, and if I check it in FFPROBE I get a massive stream of PPS and SPS errors. Tried dump_extra=all and got a 0kb file...

Comment: What was the original Scenarist error? Workaround is to transcode to .264 and mux that into MKV.

Comment: @Gyan The error says "Parse error: The garbage data exists in ES. offset=0, size=773". I am also re-evaluating if we really need to go to .264. If some other format works then I believe I can change this requirement, though I did just try an m4v and it did not work. (though encoding an m4v from Adobe Media Encoder did work...)

Comment: Contacted Scenarist and they gave us a 46 page white paper on Blu-Ray specifications! Wasn't quite able to glean anything useful out of it yet, except that "Video streams shall be...MPEG-4 AVC video format ([ISO/IEC 14496-10](http://www.staroceans.org/e-book/ISO-14496-10.pdf)) compliant...". Don't know if anyone can decypher what that means or not...

Comment: The error msg is helpful. Can you generate and share a 5 second sample of both methods - direct to .264 and via mkv, using your original commands?

Comment: @Gyan for various reason sadly no, I cannot upload a file. However if you just take the above recipe that is exactly what I'm using - I only change the output file name from .mkv to .264 respectively. I'm on version 4.0.2 win64.

Comment: @Gyan One other interesting thing to note is that if I compare a file encoded `.mov->.264` vs `.mov->.mkv->.264` with FFPROBE the latter gives me some PPS and SPS errors. Otherwise everything else is exactly the same, so that appears to have something to do with the problem.

Comment: @Gyan I'm willing to pay some bounty to figure this one out! I'm at a dead end, not sure what else to do. If you can figure this out I'll put up a bounty tomorrow and sacrifice a few reputation.

Comment: I'll look at this today or tomorrow, time permitting.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks! Just tried encoding to 264 then muxing to mkv as you suggested and got the following error: `Cant write packet with unknown timestamp`. Adding `-fflags -genpts` as some other users suggested did not fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demuxed H264 stream has the same metadata content, however it is rearranged, compared to the directly produced .264 stream. So far, I don't see a way to rearrange it to match.

So, transcode directly to 264 and use mp4box to generate a stream inside a container

```
mp4box -add direct.264 -new muxed.mp4
```

You can then use ffmpeg to mux to MKV.

```
ffmpeg -i muxed.mp4 -c copy muxed.mkv
```

mp4box is part of the GPAC project. Get a nightly build from https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/

---

To do this entirely within ffmpeg, you can use the tee muxer to pipe a AVI mux to another ffmpeg instance

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0:v -vsync cfr -r fps -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset fast -tune film -b:v 20000k -maxrate 35000k -bufsize 30000k -level 4.1 -x264opts bluray-compat=1:open-gop=1:slices=4:keyint=24 -f tee "scenarist.264|[f=avi]pipe:1" | ffmpeg -f avi -i - -c copy -y playback.mkv`

Verify the

Comment: Thanks Gyan, but unfortunately this is the backend for an application I built and I need it to be portable so GPAC does not work. However I did just figure out a ridiculous but workable solution. I cannot mux .264 directly to .mkv, however this is the only workflow I've found that does the trick: `mov -> 264 -> avi -> mkv`. For whatever reason the avi muxer seems to regenerate whatever metadata is needed for the mkv... Because they're all just stream copies it isn't too slow. Do you know of a way to go `264 -> avi -> mkv` in one process?

Comment: Added workaround. There are bugs with the method you've used. In H264 streams with hierarichical B-frames, ffmpeg may reorder B-frames presentation order. However, Blu-ray limits the B-frame count, so you may be OK. Test a few MKVs, though.

Comment: What's the barrier with GPAC? It's FOSS and cross-platform. Installation is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I couldn't find a portable version of GPAC, just an exe? Your tee mux recipe gave me a better idea, why not just transcode a .264 and .mkv at the same time? Then I don't need to mux the .264 later, that can just go straight to scenarist and I can mux the mkv with chapters and audio later. Don't know why I didn't think of it before!

Comment: *why not just transcode a .264 and .mkv at the same time?* --> that's double CPU + RAM.

Comment: Even with the tee muxer?

Comment: The bitstream format demanded by a container like MP4/MKV requires a global_header, which has to be implemented by the encoder. `.264` requires in-band headers, which is the direct opposite. The tee muxer is meant for when identical streams have multiple recipients.

Comment: I see, I'm not very familiar with headers. It did seem to work though without a problem, does that make sense? I didn't benchmark it or test it very thoroughly beyond running out a 10 second test video (which seemed to work okay, and scenarist at least imported)